# PutText overlap issue - image

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

I'm using FLIR Lepton camera to capture the thermal image, then try to display the temperature on the image using PutText method but getting very strange result. Any advice is appreciated in advance.

Code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

image_counter = 0
video = cv2.VideoCapture(0,cv2.CAP_DSHOW)
video.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FOURCC, cv2.VideoWriter.fourcc('Y','1','6',' '))
video.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_CONVERT_RGB, 0)
if video.isOpened():
    rval, frame = video.read()
else:
    rval = False
clahe = cv2.createCLAHE(clipLimit=2.0, tileGridSize=(8,8))
while rval:
rval, frame = video.read()
frame_roi = frame[:-3, :]
normed = cv2.normalize(frame_roi, None, 0, 255, cv2.NORM_MINMAX, cv2.CV_8U)
cl1 = clahe.apply(normed)
nor = cv2.cvtColor(cl1, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR) 
color = cv2.applyColorMap(nor, cv2.COLORMAP_JET)
for i in range(frame.shape[0]):
    for j in range(frame.shape[1]):
        pixel = frame [i,j]
        Temp_C = pixel/100 - 273.15
        color = cv2.putText(color, "{:.2f}".format(Temp_C), (10,30), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.45, cv2.LINE_AA)
        print (Temp_C)
cv2.imshow("preview", cv2.resize(color, dsize=(640,480), interpolation=cv2.INTER_LINEAR))
key = cv2.waitKey(100)
if key == 27: # exit on ESC
    break
```

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: your puttext function is inside a double for loop. so you print in the same place the temperature of all the pixels (one overlapping the other). Most probably also a number like 21.82 in a pretty small window (as far as i remember lepton is like 32x32 pixels) and then you resize it to a big image. What should you do?, depends on what do you want to show, maybe choose something like the average and calculate that and then display it. Also put puttext after resize and do resize before imshow in a separate line. The most important is to avoid the overlap

Comment: @api55, thanks for your guidance. Could you advise where I should put the puttext function? Thanks

Comment: @api55 you are a lifesaver... god.... now it looks better.... thank you so much for the guidance!

Comment: @api55, Hello, I made the changes accordingly, but overlap issue still exist (1st digit), could you take a look and advise please? I tried resize before imshow in separate, but getting 640x480 screen with 160x100 video stream....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look here:

```
for i in range(frame.shape[0]):
    for j in range(frame.shape[1]):
        pixel = frame [i,j]
        Temp_C = pixel/100 - 273.15
        color = cv2.putText(color, "{:.2f}".format(Temp_C), (10,30), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.45, cv2.LINE_AA)
        print (Temp_C)
```

You are basically looping through each pixel of the image, getting its temperature and writing the temperature on the image.

But you are writing *every* temperature at *one* location of the image; at `(10, 30)`, so if there were 1000 pixels, you are writing 1000 temperatures on a single spot on the image.

It wouldn't be possible to spread out every temperature detected on the image with no overlapping, unless each text is only one pixel in size, which would cover the entire screen.

You could try something like this:

```
for i in range(0, frame.shape[0], 50):
    for j in range(0, frame.shape[1], 50):
        pixel = frame [i,j]
        Temp_C = pixel/100 - 273.15
        color = cv2.putText(color, "{:.2f}".format(Temp_C), (i,j), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.45, cv2.LINE_AA)
        print (Temp_C)
```

Where the temperature of every next 50 pixels is displayed on the image.